# Comprehensive guide for Mobile Display / Resolution

Tags: mobile, resolution

I'm building a website and I'm really strugling with what width to build the thing at. I've built it at 300px so that it can go on a mobile device comfortably.

However, as I'm planning on having a lot of images/videos, it could do with being larger, lets say at 420px. But the problem is the sheer range of mobile device dimensions that exist today.

I've tested 420 on my Samsung Galaxy S4 and I'm happy with it, because the phone has a Pixel density of 441? However, my mum just got a brand new phone which only has a Pixel density of 294, so the 420px design is way too large for this.

In an ideal world you would think that screens would only get bigger, or at least try to get to a standard size, like what we used to have on desktops, but this obviously isn't the case. So are there any charts out there that can give me some sort of idea of the sizes of modern devices, specifically Mobile.

And I'm not talking about what the box says, i.e. 720 x 1280, I mean exactly what the screen is capable of displaying nicely without having to scale up or down

Answer (score 4):

For responsive purposes, you can use the devices resolution conventions:

[image]

By using these dimensions, you cover a maximum of devices.

Comment: Very helpful graphic. I could have used this a while ago! Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful. Just for extra clarity, do you know where the Samsung J3 fits into this graphic? A search on google suggests that it's `720 x 1280 pixels (~294 ppi pixel density)` Clearly it's not a Tablet, so where does the `720px` come from vs the `294`? If I have worded that correctly.

Comment: @FootBlogger: CSS pixels aren't the same as actual pixels…

Comment: Thanks @wb9688, but that doesn't really answer my question. I've just tested my site on the `Samsung J3` and it looks very much like it does on the `S4`, just that the text is a little bit smaller

Answer (score 1):

You will not find a resolution that will fit all or one that works far better than others, you will need to use media queries or agent sniffing to detect which phone is being used.

It is now common to see smartphones using desktop resolutions, especially when the device is in landscape. Many smart phones sold in the last few years are capable of FHD (1080p), Some now support QHD 2K (1440p) e.g Samsung Galaxy 7, and even Sony have released a 4K UHD (2160p).

You shouldn't focus on making your website one site but rather use media queries to support a wide range of devices, if this is a mobile only site, then still you need to have a flexible layout.

*Getting familiar with 5 sizes:*

- (XS) Extra Small
- (S) Small
- (M) Medium
- (L) Large
- (XL) Extra Large

*Bootstrap determines these sizes as:*

> **[SOURCE](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints)**
>
> ```
> // Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 544px)
> // No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap
>
> // Small devices (landscape phones, 544px and up)
> @media (min-width: 544px) { ... }
>
> // Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
> @media (min-width: 768px) { ... }
>
> // Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
> @media (min-width: 992px) { ... }
>
> // Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
> @media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
> ```

*Zurb Foundation determines these sizes as:*

> [SOURCE](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/media-queries.html#default-media-queries)
>
> ```
> /* Small only */
> @media screen and (max-width: 39.9375em) {}
>
> /* Medium and up */
> @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {}
>
> /* Medium only */
> @media screen and (min-width: 40em) and (max-width: 63.9375em) {}
>
> /* Large and up */
> @media screen and (min-width: 64em) {}
>
> /* Large only */
> @media screen and (min-width: 64em) and (max-width: 74.9375em) {}
> ```

Both Zurb and Bootstrap frameworks are used by millions of sites worldwide, these resolutions are tested, and work very well. You shouldn't need to do research, as the people behind these have done that for you. Make your site future proof, cater using media queries.

Comment: No offence, but back in 2009-10 I was building what we called "future proof" websites based on the screens we had back then. Skip forward a few years and those websites don't work effectively due to mobile devices and screens, so is there such a thing as "Future Proof" anymore? Bottom line is, I've built a site at 320px and it works on mobile, and actually looks good on desktop, but it's ability to display good video and photo gallery means I'd rather it be a little bigger. So I just want to know the next best size up from 320 that will work. Preferably, **420px**

Comment: No offence taken and I hope you don't take offence but you sound like a old dog who can't learn new tricks. You should stop thinking about 'A' resolution and start thinking 'Resolution Range'. Media queries are future proof and if you incorporate media queries with `max-width:` rather than fixed width then your website will be future proof. Obviously, this isn't a forever thing, but it will last a hell of lot longer than using fixed.

Comment: I am capable of learning new tricks, and I've built responsive and mobile sites, but I'm at a point where I just can't be bothered catering for all the constant changes

Comment: Then have a website that works on a small portion of mobiles. You will not find a resolution to FIT all.

Comment: Meaning what exactly? 320px, or 420px?

Comment: 320px if you want to cater for people with smart phones older than a decade, or those in 3rd world countries, but that said... even those have smartphones.

Comment: 1st GEN iphone was 320px, that was released in 2007... that's close to 10 years. To understand the most common resolution you need to know the niche, and whereabouts of the people your site targets. Since looking at popularity charts of resolutions will not help you, since niche/countries impact on those stats.

Comment: So why not just say that it's not a problem to expand the site to 420px?

Comment: You could do that but from a user experience stand point, that sucks... so much weight space and you will be forcing users to play a game of endless scroll down, unless the website has minimal text then ya, 420px will be fine.

Comment: Personally I would just use `max-width: 100%` on the elements within a container, then `max-width: 1024px` on the container itself but then again, I know nothing about the website your building.

Comment: My website is a blog / magazine, and does feature heavily on text in the articles, but the design is very minimal, meaning that I can get away with a narrow column, like actual paper based magazines have. The only downside of the site I have is the 300px video being that bit too small, while I feel that a 420px would be so much better.

Comment: If the videos are hosted on YouTube then do not use the fixed width embed and opt to use [Fluid Width](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php), this will fill the container size.

Comment: See, I asked a question about fluid videos the other day and couldn't get a straight answer. Someone mentioned padding, but that it could only be used effectively if I knew the original dimensions, and as the videos I'm going to be embedding are uploaded by other people, I will not always know the correct padding.

Comment: The padding within the link I provided is controls the height of the video, not the width. So using the default, should fit all videos, regardless of the source of video.

Comment: In otherwords, the aspect ratio of the video is preserved. Some may have black borders, such as those you sometimes get when viewing a DVD, so for example: if a video is 16:9 DVD, you get no borders, if the video is 4:3 you would get black borders on the left and right, and if the video is 2:1 you get borders etc. This is controlled by YouTubes player, not your website

Comment: So, don't think of the resolution of peoples videos, think aspect ratio: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_(image)

Comment: It's an interesting sollution, but I feel that even if I had a "full sized" website, it would only consist of 2 columns - A 300px sidebar, and a main section measuring around 420px - With a full width of around 800px ( with padding/margins ), so even with this design, I'd be happy to fix the video width at the 420px needed for the main column.

Comment: Yep that would work too. Sidebars are always the problem with mobile design.

Comment: Which is why I'm keen on just incorporating what would ordinarily go in a sidebar (Which in this case are a few Ad's, Subscribe button, links to other articles) into the main column of the website, and just fix the whole thing at 420px. Just need to be sure that the 420px width will be visible to most of my potential viewers